# Wordpress reset password email is not working - woocommerce and checkmail does work

Tags: wordpress, email, php-7.4

I have a bit of an odd issue on our Wordpress site that is currently under development on a subdomain of our primary domain.

It is a basic Wordpress with Woocommerce and a couple other plugins for payments, nothing too fancy. I configured Woocommerce, ordered some products and it is all working fine. I am receiving a confirmation mail from the admin email I provided. Let's say `no-reply@example.com` even though the website is hosted on `new.example.com`.

Now one of the admins forgot his password, so he requested a new one, but no email was delivered. I did some debugging and didn't receive one myself either, even though I am still receiving Woocommerce emails.

So I googled and found the `Check Email` plugin. By default it wanted to use my own personal `@gmail` for the `From` header, so I tested that one, but also with a custom `From: no-reply@example.com`. I didn't receive the one sent from my Gmail (obviously), but I did receive the no-reply version. So I am sure that `wp_mail()` is working.

Which made me think if there was an old setting in the `wp_options` table, or any other table. So I searched them all for `no-reply@example.com` and `mypersonal@gmail.com`, on all columns, every single row. I also performed a search on all files within the `wordpress/` directory to see if there is anything hardcoded (using `grep -rnw 'wordpress/' -e 'tried a couple varieties'`). I did this because because wordpress says the following on the settings page:

> Dit adres wordt gebruikt voor administratieve doeleinden. Als je het wijzigt, sturen wij een e-mail naar je nieuwe adres om het te bevestigen. Het nieuwe adres zal niet actief worden voordat het is bevestigd.
>
> ROUGHLY TRANSLATED: This email address will be used for admin purposes, if you edit, a verification email will be send. It won't get active before it is verified.

When I first added this email address, it didn't even exist yet, now the mailbox does, but I am not getting a new verification email, after changing it to another email on the same domain, to my gmail, nothing.

So I need your help... What else could I try to fix this issue?

**Summary of what I tried**

- WooCommerce works just fine
- `Check Email` plugin works just fine, as long as I use any email from `@example.com`
- Checked the entire database for old email settings which might be overriding anything
- Checked every single file in the wordpress directory for a wrong hardcoded email

**System**

I have a Wordpress install on a Debian 10 Buster VPS with PHP7.4

Answer (score 1):

I always have problems with the wordpress email system & have spent hours going around in circles with it in the past. First thing I do when setting up a new site is to send using Amazon's SES service - you can set it up through the AWS console & there's a plugin at https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ses/ that allows you to add the settings easily.

Comment: Great suggestion, will definitely take it into consideration. $0.10 for every 1000 emails is pennies... I cannot mark it as the answer though, because it doesn't really solve the core issue I am having. Want to figure out what is causing this.

Comment: It's reliable, we've been using it 3-4 years now and wouldn't change. From experience, whatever you use, if you're not sending from the same domain the install is on it doesn't like it, but as a default it tries to use your email from your user profile.

Comment: Another thing to consider as well is that the wp_mail() doesn't have any SPF/DKIM support so it could well be that they're being sent as they should be, just the gmail/yahoo filters are rejecting them. WooCommerce might be getting through because they get a higher rating on their algorithm & less likely to be good old fashioned spam.

Comment: I've just added 3x new users from a dev wp setup not running SES yet - try the same and let me know what you get. 1st user - add a gmail or whatever email address you can access. 2nd user add a [link](https://temp-mail.org/en/) email address. Make sure you select 'send new user email' - I didn't get the gmail, but did get the temp mail & outlook ones. If you get some through but not others, it's a deliverability/spam/trust issue as opposed to something wrong with your WP core

Comment: RE: `wp_mail() doesn't have any SPF/DKIM support (..)` - I get what you mean, and yes that makes perfect sense. But I tried it on a tempmail as well, and doesn't work either. On Gmail & a tempmail, the `Check Email` gets through perfectly fine, as long as I make sure I set the `From` header to something from this domain. So apparantly the SPF records are setup fine(which I believe I did correctly), so that callback seems to work (`Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of webmaster@example.com designates xxxx:xx:(..) as permitted sender)`).

Comment: RE: `but as a default it tries to use your email from your user profile` - Any idea where I could find this in the code? Because then I might be able to hard-code that to the correct email, and see if that solves the problem. Then at least I know the root cause.

Comment: I believe Email is stored with username and password in `user` table as user data? Not in user_meta. Perhaps going into database and reviewing (changing) those details may assist?

Comment: When you received the WooCommerce & Check Mail emails in the past, what was the from address? wordpress@yourdomain? Did you specify that anywhere on setup of these plugins? In the dashboard, under Settings > General, there's an admin email address field - is that @yourdomain or a gmail?

Comment: If you need to change the admin email, in the database it's under options > admin_email